# Boolean algebra minimization

Tags: boolean-logic, digital-logic

F = ABC + AC + C'D'

is there a way to minimise this function even further because i want to make the circuit diagram with only 2 input nand gates

any suggestions ?
thanks

Comment: This reduces to AC + C'D'. But I still don't think you can make it with only 2 NAND gates.

Comment: @shree.pat18: A more logical parsing of his request would be (2 input) NAND gates, rather than 2 (input NAND) gates.  Yes, any boolean function can be implemented with 2-input NAND gates; see my answer below.

Comment: Yeah, didn't occur to me. Been a while since I actually worked on logic gates :P

Answer (score 1):

**First, simplify:**

```
F = ABC + AC + C'D'
F = AC(B + 1) + C'D'
F = AC + C'D'
```

**Now, put in terms of ANDs and NOTs only:**

```
F = (AC + C'D')''        [double negation]
F = ( (AC)'(C'D')' )'    [DeMorgan's]
```

**Then noting that:**

- NOT can be implemented via 2-input NAND by tying its inputs together.
- AND can be implemented via 2-input NAND by combining NAND and NOT.

**You should be able to implement `F` in this form directly using only 2-input NANDs.**

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for the minimalization using a Karnaugh Table.

[image: This is the solution for the minimalization using a Karnaugh Table.]

Comment: I kinda drew the solution in Paint instead of using something more sophisticated, please don't sue me for that.

Comment: Thnx for ur efforts !!